# Line break in title in LyX

Tags: lyx, line-breaking

I am using Beamer Article (standard class) in LyX. I have tried to break my title into many lines as I choose but I failed. I have tried

```
 "...line 1...  ctrl+enter 
...line2..."
```

but in the PDF output instead of

```
"line 1
line 2"
```

it shows

```
"line 1  line 2".
```

Please help me.

Comment: I think this might have something to do with Beamer Article. I can't get line break in the title in pure LaTeX either.

Answer (score 1):

You can manually break a line with either:

- `\\`
- `\newline`
- `\hfill \break`

If none of these solutions suit you, you can simply jump two lines in your TeX document:

```
line 1

line 2
```

If I remember that correctly it has the same effect as creating a new paragraph.

Also notice that, depending on your text editor, `Ctrl+Enter` can have the effect of inserting `\\`.

Acording to [Lyx wiki](https://wiki.lyx.org/Tips/FrequentlyUsedShortcuts):

> `Ctrl-Enter` Add new line to multi-line equation environment, if necessary creating multi-line (eqnarray) environment

The preriquisite is `math` mode here...